# trigger_error('Database query failed: '.mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR); -> security issue?

Tags: php, security

i've a question regarding this line:

```
$db_conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $username, $password) or trigger_error('Query failed: ' . mysql_error($db), E_USER_ERROR);
```

i use this code to connect to DB. from documentation E_USER_ERROR says that interrupts the execution of the script but what i would like to know is if this poses a security risk showing some information about error/code that the users should not be supposed to read.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In short: Yes. Never expose *internal* error messages to any *external* user. The reason is, that the more information you throw out, the easier it can be for possible attackers to find weak points of your application, server, .... On the other side regular users are usually not interested in any internals, thus there is no downside in just hide them. However, you should log them.

Answer (score 1):

Never report internal error to user.
You should enable error reporting in authoring with sintax `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and disable it when you publish your site/app with `error_reporting(0);`

Hope you will find this usefull :-)

Answer (score 0):

> what i would like to know is if this poses a security risk showing some information about error/code that the users should not be supposed to read.

Not if you do the right thing, and turn off error reporting on production web sites.

That's why using `trigger_error()` is much, much better than e.g. `die()` - the latter will always show the error message, while the former can be made to shut up.